# Techniques and algorithms for reducing samples count

Tags: android, algorithm, signals, signal-processing, scichart

I am recording the audio stream using `AudioRecord` class.

I am reading samples to a buffer with size of `2040 samples`.

After reading samples, they are processed and reduced to size of `170 samples`.

Even in this case there are a lot of samples to draw them in real time, I have not managed to configure `SciChart` library to show this samples correctly, they are compressed however I need to make a chart wider.

I am processing the ECG signal, therefore, all main components like R peak, QRS complex and other should be left without change.

[image]

Is there any techniques that could be applied to reduce samples count, but do not spoil the signal.

I think techniques like moving average won't work, as far they are used for smoothing the signal, however in my case I don't need to smooth it.

I would be grateful for any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[SciChart android](http://scichart.com/android-chart-features/) should be able to draw 2,040 samples in real-time (actually, [millions](https://www.scichart.com/android-chart-performance-comparison/)). It includes methods to automatically downsample waveforms without visual loss of data, and in [performance benchmarks can draw a million points on Android devices](http://scichart.com/android-chart-performance-comparison/).

Have you got a code sample? Maybe something is wrong in the configuration.